# ORA-01005: null password given; logon denied

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssas, bids

I have created a SSAS Database pro grammatically using SQL Server AMO namespaces. It has create successfully. But When I'm going to explore the data using BIDS of the Data source It is prompting an error like this,

ORA-01005: null password given; logon denied

My Connection String is

```
    @"Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle.1;Data Source=//cmbtrndb02/hector;Password=trnint16;User ID=trnint16;Intergrated Security=yes";
```

I have used the ConnectionStringSecurity Property as "unchanged" but it gives the same error.

```
ds.ConnectionStringSecurity = ConnectionStringSecurity.Unchanged;
```

What could be the problem for this.

Comment: Something is messed up here: you say you are using SQL Server (components), but what you have here is an ORACLE error message (and connection string). Try to straighten that out please.

Comment: I'm creating a data model against a oracle database , and that's why It's popping an error from Oracle Provider

Comment: Well, what is strange is that you specify both "Username/Password" and "Integrated Security=yes" (I would have used "True" or "SSPI" here, but anyway).

Comment: remove Intergrated Security=yes or change it to Intergrated Security=no

Answer (score 10):

Old post but maybe this helps someone out (like it helped me):

If you're using "System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure" on your project (maybe you are casting the DbContext to an ObjectContext for some reason?) you will be getting this error (ORA-01005).

As I finally found out, you can easily avoid it just by adding "Persist Security Info=true" on your "Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client"'s string connection.

Comment: This is a real solution to the problem.

Answer (score 2):

If for some reason you really need to obtain the connection string from other connection, like user2306318 refers, you need to add the option "Persist Security Info=True" to your connection string.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to include the password in the connectionstring as follows:
if your user name is *carl* and your password is *bullet56* then:

> connectionString="Data Source=LocalHost;User ID=carl;Unicode=True;**Password=bullet56**"

Hope it will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The new connection objects are losing the passwords when you use objcon.connectstring. Maybe you are reading the connectstring from the connection object (=without password) somewhere in the code instead of providing the complete connectstring including the password.

Answer (score 0):

For example

> gacutil /u Policy.**2.102**.Oracle.DataAccess

set your version assembly

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same error in spring boot with oracle 19c, I just changed the jdk version to latest i.e 13 and it solved my problem.